# DecisionTreeClassifier cannot take one-hot encoded classes?

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-trees, multiclass-classification, one-hot-encoding

[image]

I got `ValueError: Found array with dim 3. None expected <= 2.` I dont know which array has dim 3?

DecisionTreeClassifier cannot take one-hot encoded classes?

But from this page it should support? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html

label is constructed by

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
label = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(y.values.reshape(-1,1))
```

where y is like
[image]

Comment: `label_train` should have dimensions of `(1490,1)` where each value is the class label. The DecisionTreeClassifier has the capability to return probabilities for each class or predicted multiclass labels it finds in the training labels.

Comment: @m13op22 thank you! but this is not mentioned in the sklearn docs?

Comment: You're right, it's not super clear in the `fit()` method docs. It's mentioned [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#classification) and in the Iris example (with 3 classes). If you copy & paste the Iris code you can see the outputs and how the data should be structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to integer encode your labels instead of one-hot encoding them.

[1, 0, 0] -> 0

[0, 1, 0] -> 1

[0, 0, 1] -> 2

so that the labels for multiclass classification (with K classes) that you provide to sklearn are just integers in the set $\{0,1,...,K-1 \}$

Comment: thank you! but this is not mentioned in the sklearn docs?

Comment: The sklearn docs for most classifiers look like this: 

y {array-like, sparse matrix} : of shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_outputs)

Target values.


Note that the (n_samples,) shape applies to multi-class classification tasks. n_outputs is for something completely different: multi-label tasks.  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html

Comment: n_outputs means it can accept one-hot encoding labels?

Comment: No n_outputs is not for standard multi-class classification tasks. It is for multi-label prediction tasks:  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html